# No resource identifier found for attribute 'linearLayoutOrientation' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml

I was building away with my application and all of the suden i got this error:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'linearLayoutOrientation' in package 'android'
```

I know where the error is created but i do not know how i can fix this. Can somone take a look and tell me what i am doeing wrong. I am building the application in Xamarin Studio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffd8d8d8">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Heading"
        android:text="."
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0f62ae"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="15dp" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
        android:linearLayoutOrientation="vertical" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="4.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#ff0b487f" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dataListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#ff0f62ae" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can u tell me when does this happen like on activity open or when orientation changes

Comment: It happens when i try to compile the application. So when i press f5 the error instantly will occure

Comment: remove android:linearLayoutOrientation:"vertical" it has no means from your layout and then compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove

```
android:linearLayoutOrientation="vertical"
```

from `edittext` tag 
and add

```
 android:orientation="vertical"
```

in `LinearLayout` tag

Comment: Thank you very much i will mark this as awnser as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

remove `android:linearLayoutOrientation="vertical"`from editText from layout as you have provided it solve your issue in this context